# JQuery code to change selectable dropdown options based on radio button selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can i change the selectable dropdown options based on radio button selection.
here is the code am using

**HTML:**

```
<div id="manage">
    <div>
        <label>Operating Systems</label>
        <select id="OS" onchange="browserlist();">
            <option value="win7 32">Windows 7 - 32</option>
            <option value="win7 64">Windows 7 - 64</option>
            <option value="Vista 32">Windows Vista - 32</option>
            <option value="Vista 64">Windows Vista - 64</option>
            <option value="Win8 X64">Windows 8 - X64</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Browsers</label>
        <select id="browsers" onchange="browserDet();">
            <option value="ie">IE</option>
            <option value="vista">Vista</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Versions</label>
        <select id="version"></select>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Test Scripts</label>
        <select id="testscriptlist">
            <option value="1">test1</option>
            <option value="2">test2</option>
            <option value="3">test3</option>
            <option value="4">test34</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Server:</label>
        <input type="text" id="server" value="" />
    </div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: "/getJobs",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (jobs) {
        //alert(jobs);                          
        if (jobs.length == 0) {
            alert("There are no scheduled Jobs");
            $("#jobsTable").hide();
        } else {
            //jobs.forEach(function(job) {
            $.each(jobs, function (key, value) {
                alert(value.jobid);
                var tabString = '<tr><td>' + value._id + '</td><td>' + value.os + '</td><td>' + value.browser + '</td><td>' + value.version + '</td><td>' + value.script + '</td><td>' + value.server + '</td><td>' + '<input  type="radio" name="joblist" onclick="myfunc(this);"  id= ' + value.jobid + 'value=' + value.jobid + '/> </td></tr>';
                $("#jobsTable").append(tabString);
            });
        }
    }
});
}
```

Following code used in the onclick of radio button .while choosing radio button i will get radio button values and have to change selectable dropdown options based on the radio button selection.

```
function myfunc(ele) {

    var $tr = $(ele).parent().parent();
    var os = $tr.find("td:eq(1)").html();

    var browsers = $tr.find("td:eq(2)").html();
    var version = $tr.find("td:eq(3)").html();
    var testscriptlist = $tr.find("td:eq(4)").html();
    var server = $tr.find("td:eq(5)").html();

}
```

Comment: where is your radio button????

Comment: var tabString = '<tr><td>' + value._id + '</td><td>' + value.os + '</td><td>' + value.browser + '</td><td>' + value.version + '</td><td>' + value.script + '</td><td>' + value.server + '</td><td>' + '<input  type="radio" name="joblist" onclick="myfunc(this);"  id= ' + value.jobid + 'value=' + value.jobid + '/> </td></tr>';

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little unclear, but from your code, I'm guessing you want to select specific values of the dropdowns after a radio button is selected.

[jQuery .val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) is what you want.

```
function myfunc(ele) {

    var $tr = $(ele).parent().parent();
    var os = $tr.find("td:eq(1)").html();

    var browsers = $tr.find("td:eq(2)").html();
    var version = $tr.find("td:eq(3)").html();
    var testscriptlist = $tr.find("td:eq(4)").html();
    var server = $tr.find("td:eq(5)").html();

    $("#OS").val(os);
    $("#browsers").val(browsers);
    $("#version").val(version);
    $("#testscriptlist").val(version);
    $("#server").val(server);
}
```